# How to resize a drawn oval in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I need to resize a drawn oval in Java, I created this code for it:

FrameView.java

```
package tutorial;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameView{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        BallCreation c = new BallCreation();
        f.add(c);
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

BallCreation.java

```
package tutorial;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BallCreation extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int height = 10;
    private int width = 10;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton button1;

    public BallCreation(){
        panel = new JPanel();

        button1 = new JButton("Click");
        add(button1);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                height = height + 2;
                width = width + 2;
            }
        });


    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(10, 10, width, height);
    }
}
```

The problem is is that it isn't working, I am not sure how I can make the oval refresh to its new size. I think it should be working, but for some reason the button doesn't parse the new height and width on to the `paintComponent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `repaint()` at the end of your `actionPerformed` method , or you won't see the change (unless you minimize then restore your window for instance, to force a repaint of the area).

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                height = height + 2;
                width = width + 2;
                repaint();
            }
        });
```